# Building modules for a precompiled kernel

Tags: linux-kernel

Actually I am learning kernel module programming and I have learnt how to build and insert a kernel module but now I want to learn that how to build kernel module for a precompiled kernel.

Answer (score 0):

You need a kernel headers package.

See
https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/build-linux-kernel-module-against-installed-kernel-source-tree.html
or
https://askubuntu.com/q/515407